# how to make certain options bold in select using angularjs filter and ng-options

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-filter, angularjs-controller

I am using the AngularJS ng-options to populate certain select element. I would like to make some options bold and make them disabled. I am trying to achieve this using the `filter` along with `ng-options`. I am able to read the values on the controller side of the angular js but I am unable to make them bold and disabled. I checked lot of answers but some reason none worked for me. Any help would be appreciated.

`HTML Code for the select`:

```
//HTML SELECT
<select class="form-control" id="ObjectId" ng-change="ObjectEventEPCsChange()" ng-model="formdata.ObjectId" ng-options='ObjectId.value as ObjectId.text  for ObjectId in ObjectIds |filter:MyFilter'>
    <option class="dropdown-item" value='' selected> Choose </option>
    <option class="dropdown-item" value="{{ ObjectId.value  }}"> {{ ObjectId.text }} </option>
</select>
```

`ÀngularJS Controller function for filter`:
//Make some options bold and Disabled based on conditions

```
$scope.MyFilter = function(item) {
    if(item.text == 'ABCD')
    {
        console.log(item.toString().replace(item.text,"<strong>"+item.text+"</strong>"));
        return item.toString().replace(item.text,"<b>"+item.text+"</b>")
    }
    else
    {
        return item.toString().replace(item.text,"&nbsp;"+item.text);
    }
}
```

`Populating of the options`:
I have the options in nodejs and following are the type of options that are populated into the Select:

```
var ObjectTypeOptions  =    [
                                {value:'Option-1',      text:'Option-1'},
                                {value:'Option-2',      text:'Option-2'},
                                {value:'Option-3',      text:'Option-3'},
                                {value:'ABCD',          text:'ABCD'},
                                {value:'Option-4',      text:'Option-4'},
                            ];

var returnData = {'ObjectTypeOptions': ObjectTypeOptions};

callback(returnData);
```

Following is the Angularjs method that returns the data to HTML and populates the select:

```
//On load of the page populate the drop-downs
$scope.init = function () {
    $http({
        url: "/populateFields",
        method: "GET"
    }).success(function(response) {
        $scope.ObjectIds    =   response.ObjectTypeOptions;
    }).error(function(error) {
        console.log(error);
    });
};
```

Comment: please post an example of the data you operate with. Or better, write some demo in Plunker or similar

Comment: Done, Please check

Comment: Do you use any bootstrap theme? The native browser dropdown does not have bold style option as I know

Comment: Yes I am using Bootstrap 4.

Answer (score 1):

You can use ng-repeat and ng-disabled for disabling like:

```js
function TodoCrtl($scope) {
$scope.ObjectIds = [{
  value: "option1",
  text: "Option 1",
  class: "bold"
},{
  value: "option2",
  text: "Option 2",
  disabled: true
}, {
  value: "option3",
  text: "Option 3"
}];
}
```

```css
.bold {
 font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.1.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>ng-click</title>
</head>
<body>
<div ng-controller="TodoCrtl">
<select class="form-control" id="ObjectId" ng-change="ObjectEventEPCsChange()" ng-model="formdata.ObjectId">
    <option class="dropdown-item" value='' selected> Choose </option>
    <option ng-repeat="ObjectId in ObjectIds" class="dropdown-item" ng-class="ObjectId.class" ng-disabled="ObjectId.disabled" value="{{ ObjectId.value  }}"> {{ ObjectId.text }} </option>
</select>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks in this way the `Bold` would work, How can I make them `disabled`? I have to use the filter right?

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed explanation and code. This would work perfectly for me. Just out of curiosity is there a way this can be done by  using the `filter` just so that if the data is coming from the database where I do not have the option to add the `class` and `disabled` at the origin itself then wanted to know how can I do that using the `filter` option.